# Primeng Checkbox disable Option Conflicting with ngmodel

Tags: angular, html, primeng

I have a list of checkbox. The disabled option is working fine when no ngmodel is binded.

```
<div class="ui-g">
   <div *ngFor="let role of listContactRole" class="ui-g-6">
     <p-checkbox value="{{role.id}}" label= {{role.displayName}}" 
              name="planRole" [disabled]="role.isEnabled">
     </p-checkbox>
   </div>
</div>
```

But when I am binding ngmodel="selectedPlanRoles" the disabled option does not work anymore. Any Help?

```
<div class="ui-g">
       <div *ngFor="let role of listContactRole" class="ui-g-6">
         <p-checkbox value="{{role.id}}" label="{{role.displayName}}"  [(ngModel)]="selectedPlanRoles" name="planRole" [disabled]="role.isEnabled"></p-checkbox>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's working fine, you can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d1hazg

Comment: thank u for the reply. But model is not binding. The checkbox was supposed to be checked as per the code. But it's unchecked. Can u help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set string in `selectedPlanRoles` as checkbox will be selected only if it's value is string. Something like:

```
selectedPlanRoles = ['1'];
listContactRole =[
    {
      id: 1,
      isEnabled: false,
      displayName: 'Test'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      isEnabled: false,
      displayName: 'Test 2'
    }
];
```

You can check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtesd8)